# Adding alt tags to images to the mini-products-list

Tags: seo

The images I have given a label to are producing alt tags if it is their product image, but on the product slider `.mini-products-list` they don't.

Where is the file to edit this? And what variable should be under the alt tag.

To see the problem, check the alt tags of the images on the bottom that scroll:

https://www.mitchellfineartgallery.com/stockroom/affordable-art/the-key

I have located the file here:

```
/app/design/frontend/mfag/default/template/catalog/product/related.phtml
```

To generate the alt tag it is using,

```
  alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

But this doesn't give anything. Anyone know how I can get it to correctly display the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `title` attribute for show image label on hover. Image's `alt` attribute is called when your image is not found in your site. For show your image label you have to also add label from admin side as attached image. Hope it works.

[image]

You have to tried below code:

```
<img title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Comment: This isn't a solution? I know that's the code I'm using. I have the label's applied to all of the images. The alt just doesn't generate. What code do I need to do that? I haven't done any custom coding here, alt just appears empty from magento's end.

Comment: Have you added image labels from admin side?

Comment: Yes. That's why this is a bit confusling. The labels are there it just doesn't send anything through when it's called.

Comment: Main-image has the alt tag, but those scrolling ones don't.

Comment: I think you have to try with load product using id like $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); and check it's work or not.

Comment: Could you please show how? The img is loaded with, <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSizeW,$_imgSizeH); ?> 

I was thinking $_product should be loaded.

Comment: Use lIke below:
$prodmodel =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($prodmodel , 'small_image'), null, true) ?>

Comment: No luck :( Still just blank.

Comment: I think the trouble is getImageLabel() doesn't do what it should. I ran a vardump on $prodmodel and the variable is there.

Comment: Then you have to try  with  $prodmodel->getData('image_label').